Empirical basis for the limit of the comparative method?
I've heard lots of different numbers thrown around in the literature to the 'upper bound' of how far back in time the comparative method can go. The most pessimistic numbers hover around 7,000 years ago, more optimistic numbers go up to 10,000 or 12,000 years ago. However, I've never seen anyone actually cite a source for these numbers. They seem to represent the collective intuition of the field. Is there any methodological justification or empirical basis for these figures, or are they really just guesswork?

How would you gather empirical data for such things without a time machine? The whole reason the comparative method is a thing is that we can’t do empirical research for prehistory.

It should be possible to make an argument about the number of tractable roots using glottochronology, but I haven't encountered a serious quantification of that in the literature.

See "Beyond Lumping and Splitting" for some discussion of this. The short version is that no real empirical value has been established.

@HBI The "probabilistic issues in historical linguistics" one (Baxter and Ramer). Didn't realize there was another paper with that title!

@JanusBahsJacquet I'm inclined to agree, but linguists keep figures like these anyways! I can't even track down the origin of these figures.

@HBI They are based on research, calculations and logic (even if it may sometimes seem more like they’re plucked out of thin air), but those are by definition non-empirical. The figures are essentially based on projecting attested rates of migration, language change (very variant), technological advancements, etc., further back in time – all useful points of evidence, but also all rather vague and difficult to quantify with much certainty. This is also part of why the numbers end up varying so much.

@JanusBahsJacquet Could you point me towards any publications where the rationale behind such an estimation is demonstrated?

I suppose you could argue that averaging the most accepted dates of the largest scale language families with general acceptance would give an estimate that is (albeit in only a meta-scientific sense) empirical. Meta-scientific here in the sense that it's an empirical measure of how far back linguists trust the comparative method, rather than an empirical measure of how far back it is actually reliable, i.e. it describes the scholars, not the subject of the scholarship itself
